# Mongoose exclude object in array from results

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to exclude an object in an array from the results when using find in Mongoose with MongoDB.

Query:

```
Model.findOne({
    'eventid': query
    }
    , { 
    'email': 0, 
   'guests.$.email': 0 
    }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            error: 'Error'
        }))
    }
})
```

Excluding the `'email'` field with `'email': 0` works fine. However, `'guests'` is an array with multiple objects and I want to remove the email field from the results. I get the following error:

> MongoError: Cannot exclude array elements with the positional operator.

Apparently the position operator `$` can only be used from including elements in the array, not to remove them. What would be the best way to hide the email field in the `'guests'` array.

Example dataset:

```
{ _id: 5b71c9af75a8e95dc33e7eef,
eventid: 'ALRW9by',
email: 'test@gmail.com',
guests:
 [ { _id: 5b72f16ea61d2911d806daa8 },
   { _id: 5b7306b605bf17131f80fd0a,
     userid: 'CuzcO3c',
     naam: 'John',
     email: 'test2@gmail.com' },
   { _id: 5b7306c705bf17131f80fd0b,
     userid: 'xA7A65U',
     naam: 'Ellen',
     email: 'test3@gmail.com' }
   ] }
```

Comment: have a look on documentation
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection-on-embedded-documents-in-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the dot notation `guests.email` to exclude the nested fields:

```
Model.findOne({
    'eventid': query
    }
    , { 
    'email': 0, 
    'guests.email': 0 
    }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            error: 'Error'
        }))
    }
})
```